# return NotFound() vs NoContent()

Tags: asp.net-web-api

sometimes  during a web-api call, valid request doesnot contain any records to return. In such a case should we return a

```
return NotFound() status
or
return NoContent() status?
```

I used NoContent() as the request was legit but no data was found.
I guess NotFound() is used for badrequest/404 error. Isnt?

Is there a difference?

Comment: Best practice questions are off-topic for SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a diffrent.
`NotFound()` is http Statuse code **404** and `NoContent()` is http Statuse code **204**

Little info about status codes families:

- **100s**: Informational codes: the server acknowledges the request
  initiated by the browser and that it is being processed (100–199).
- **200s**: Success codes: request received, understood, processed and
  expected info relayed to browser (200–299).
- **300s**: Redirection codes: a different destination has been substituted
  for the requested resource; further action by the browser may be
  required (300–399).
- **400s**: Client error codes: website or page not reached; page
  unavailable or there was a technical problem with the request
  (400–499).
- **500s**: Server error codes: request was accepted, but due to an error
  the server could not fulfil the request (500–599).

More about your specific situation:

- **204**: No content. Request processed, but no content sent. Headers may
  be useful.
- **404**: Not found. Very commonplace on the web. The URL is not
  recognized; the resource does not exist.